# Debug python with vscode from an external script

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

How can I debug a python program from an external app?
I'm using `guildAI` which is an external utility, that when running `guild run train.py` internally it runs `python train.py` but with other wrappers.
Is there a way, to somehow debug (like remote debugging) with vs code such applications?
 I.e tell vs code to run `guild run train.py` for me? or some other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do what's called "[local attach](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_attach-to-a-local-script)". Basically what you need to do is install ptvsd with your app, call `ptvsd.enable_attach()` and `ptvsd.wait_for_attach()`, and then use `breakpoint()` to cause the debugger to pause upon attach to let you start walking through your app.

Comment: I didn't get that, nor vs code explanation. `guild` isn't a python app, but it calls my `train.py` internally, and I don't have access to guild. Can I still attach a debugger to `train.py`?

Comment: I think the problem is that I can't find "python attach" in the debug window after starting the python script from the app